# Does a CASE statement lose alias scope in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

First of all, this SQL works:

```
select
    case
        when s.luserid > 0 then u.szusername
        when s.lgroupid > 0 then g.szgroup
        when s.lldapid > 0 then 'LDAP Group'
    end as name
from security s
left join users u on s.luserid = u.id
left join usergroups g on s.lgroupid = g.id
order by name
```

*The above block is proving ordering by alias `name` works, as well as declaring alias `name` works while the term `name` is a reserved word, which is not relevant to the question*

**My issue happens when I make a case statement with an alias in it:**

*Pay attention to the alias `useid`*

```
select
    case
        when sa.luserid > 0 then sa.luserid
        when sa.lgroupid > 0 then sa.lgroupid
        when sa.lldapid > 0 then sa.lldapid
    end as useid,
from security s
left join users u on s.luserid = u.id
left join usergroups g on s.lgroupid = g.id
order by
        case
            when 'user selection' = 'all objects by user' then useid
            else s.lobjectid
        end
```

*The text `user selection` is replaced by a parser with literal text before the SQL is run. Both the alias `useid` and `s.lobjectid` are type `bigint`.*

An error is thrown at `when 'user selection' = 'all objects by user' then useid`.

**Am I losing scope of the alias `useid` within the CASE statement?**
Why does this fail when I try to use the alias `useid` here.

By the way, this SQL works as well:

```
select
    case
        when s.luserid > 0 then u.szusername
        when s.lgroupid > 0 then g.szgroup
        when s.lldapid > 0 then 'LDAP Group'
    end as name
from security s
left join users u on s.luserid = u.id
left join usergroups g on s.lgroupid = g.id
order by
        case
            when s.lobjectid > 0 then s.lobjectid
            else s.luserid
        end
```

*The above block is proving that a `CASE` statement within an `ORDER BY` statement does work. All debates over the logical operations of the above block of SQL is irrelevant to the question, for it is simply junk example SQL.*

Comment: They are different types. Why not just `order by s.lobjectid, name` ? (you cannot order by the expression `name` , so you either have to use a subselect or repeat the case expression)

Comment: If you didn't notice, the first block of SQL works, regardless of `name` being reserved. Also, **these are only examples**. I've updated the question (specifically the second block of SQL, the one that fails) to match my actual SQL a bit more. I am terribly sorry for the horrible example SQL which was there before.

Comment: You say *"My issue happens when I make a case statement with a variable in it:"* Where is the variable? I can't see any.

Comment: @ypercube The variable is `useid`, which I define in my select statement

Comment: That is not a variable that is called an alias

Comment: Ah, that's an alias, not a variable. Anyway, you cannot use an alias (like `name`) inside a `CASE` expression in `ORDER BY`. You could repeat the whole `case when s.luserid > 0 then u.szusername when s.lgroupid > 0 then g.szgroup when s.lldapid > 0 then 'LDAP Group' end` expression or wrap the whole in a subquery (derived table or cte).

Comment: Ah, alias, yes! Sorry about that. Let me fix that. And Thanks @ypercube! I'll give that a shot!

Comment: Wait, try that? There's no doubt that will work. Yes @ypercube, you've solved my problem in the most simple way ever, and have answered my question. Yes, you do lose scope of an `alias`, declared in a `SELECT`, within a `CASE` statement outside of the `SELECT` where it was created. Thank you.

Comment: You don't actually lose scope, you can still use `ORDER BY name`. It's just a limitation of Postges that not allows the aliases inside `ORDER BY CASE` expressions.

Comment: "name" is *not* a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html). It's just a hugely overused, hardly descriptive identifier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not possible in Postgresql since it doesn't allow you to use an `ALIAS` within the same query as a field. Different from Mysql where you can do it.

To solve your problem you either create your query as a subquery and then your alias will be a field therefore can be used as:

```
select useid, lobjectid from (
  select
      case
          when sa.luserid > 0 then sa.luserid
          when sa.lgroupid > 0 then sa.lgroupid
          when sa.lldapid > 0 then sa.lldapid
      end as useid,
      lobjectid
   from security s
  left join users u on s.luserid = u.id
  left join usergroups g on s.lgroupid = g.id
  ) as t
order by
        case
            when 'user selection' = 'all objects by user' then useid
            else lobjectid
        end
```

Or you can repeat the entiry case block

```
  select
      case
          when sa.luserid > 0 then sa.luserid
          when sa.lgroupid > 0 then sa.lgroupid
          when sa.lldapid > 0 then sa.lldapid
      end as useid,
      lobjectid
   from security s
  left join users u on s.luserid = u.id
  left join usergroups g on s.lgroupid = g.id
order by
        case
            when 'user selection' = 'all objects by user' then 
                  case
                      when sa.luserid > 0 then sa.luserid
                      when sa.lgroupid > 0 then sa.lgroupid
                      when sa.lldapid > 0 then sa.lldapid
                  end
            else lobjectid
        end
```

Some engines will let you use the order number of the field on the select scope to the order by like:

```
select a, b, c from sometable order by 1, 2
```

Which means that this query will be ordered by the fields `a` and `b`